# php array to string not working online server

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have a problem. I have an array of values from database, when I try to pass it to a string with commas, it works fine on my localhost, but when I upload it to my online server, the string doesn't show any values. For example: `select from table where in (,,)` only shows the commas and in my xampp server it works excellent. Any ideas what this can be?
Here's the code:

```
<?php

$sql = "select id from users where gid = 1";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
$cat_titles=array();
while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
$cat_titles[] = $row['id '];
//  do stuff with other column
//  data if we want
}
mysql_free_result( $result );

echo "<p>\n";
foreach($cat_titles as $v)
{
    $cat_titles[]= $row['id'];

}
echo "</p>\n";

$cat_titles = implode(',',$cat_titles);
$cat_titles = substr($cat_titles,0,-2);
echo $cat_titles;
echo "select * from users where IN (".$cat_titles.")";



?>
```

Comment: Do you have the database configured?

Comment: Remove the `foreach` loop.

Comment: This never worked in the first place, and if you think it did you were probably imagining it. In the second loop you're blanking out the `$cat_titles` array with the now-empty `$row` value.

Comment: I can't understand what the foreach for!

Comment: You also have a space in the field name in your first loop, which will cause problems. You probably have error reporting disabled, otherwise you'd have see pages upon pages of warnings, put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

A number of potential issues here:

You are not handling error conditions around you database access, so if you are having issue with your queries you would never know.

Your second select query doesn't specify a field in the WHERE clause, so it will never work

This section of code does absolutely nothing and is in fact where you problem likely lies.

```
foreach($cat_titles as $v)
{
    $cat_titles[]= $row['id'];

}
```

Here $row['id'] won't have a value, so you are basically looping throguh your existing array and appending empty value to new indexes.

In all likelihood you could do this with a single query, it might help if you explain what you are actually trying to do.

You should not be using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.